# How to delete rows which have unused recode in MySQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have 2 tables: `Books` and `Authors`.

This is my SQL query to show books and their authors:

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl_books`, `tbl_author` WHERE `tbl_books`.`id` = `tbl_author`.`author_id`
```

My question is, there are more than 100 authors, but only few of them hold a book,
so I want to delete rest of the authors who don’t have any number of books. How can I do that?

Comment: You need to provide input data and desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree JOIN condition should be b.author_id = a.author_id

You can try below SQL queries,USING LEFT JOIN and NOT IN function

```
DELETE FROM tbl_author a
 WHERE a.author_id NOT IN (SELECT b.author_id 
                        FROM tbl_books b);
```

Another way using LEFT JOIN

```
DELETE a FROM tbl_author a 
  LEFT JOIN tbl_books b ON a.author_id = b.author_id
      WHERE b.author_id IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to write this query is:

```
SELECT *  -- you should be explicit about the columns here
FROM tbl_books b JOIN
     tbl_author a
     ON b.id = a.author_id;
```

Notes:

- *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.
- Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.
- Your query looks highly suspicious.  I think the `JOIN` condition should be `b.author_id = a.author_id`.

This query (and yours) will not return "author" rows with no books.  But if you actually want to delete those rows:

```
delete a from tbl_authors a
    where not exists (select 1 from tbl_books b where b.author_id = a.author_id);
```

However, it seems unlikely that you would have a database that would have authors and books, but rows in the authors table with no books.

Comment: yes you right rows in the authors table with no books. tbl_books (id, author_id ,title, img, views ,rate)
tbl_author (author_id, name, img)

Answer (score 0):

issue solved 
used NOT IN to delete unused records

DELETE FROM `tbl_author` WHERE `tbl_author`.`author_id` NOT IN (SELECT `author_id` FROM `tbl_books`)